# How to use AWS EC2 to make a low-latency outputer for AWS kinesis

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, boto3

I'm making a client to put a record for kinesis in the ec2, for testing. I'm only sending records such as `{"name":"abc","birthday":"123"}`, but it takes 100ms+ to send. I put all services in Singapore. How do I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Each call to Kinesis API must be committed to 3 availability zones to prevent event lost. You should expect latency of about 50ms in most cases.

If you want to reduce the latency you can batch multiple events into a single call using the [PutRecords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) call (instead of PutRecord). With this API call you can put up to 500 events with a single API call.

Another popular option is to use the [Kinesis Producer Library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-kpl.html) (KPL). It can help with latency (async mode), performance (batching and multithreading), ease of use and cost (aggregation).

Another option is to use an [agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html) installed on your server. The agent is monitoring some log files and can tail them to Kinesis.